# Counting seconds using QTimer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, time, count, pyqt5

I am having a hard time counting seconds in PyQGIS using QTimer. The current code waits for 1 second and prints 5 times "1" as output. I desire that after every second the output should be incremented by one.

How do I refactor it to achieve the desired result?

```py
counter = 0

def shiftPoints():
    counter=+1
    print(counter)

for i in range(5):
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, shiftPoints)
```

[image: Current Output]

I am using QGIS 3.28.1.

Comment: Yes PyQGIS is a part of Qt, but here, this is not a geographic subject, so I vote to close this one. The question is related to general IT so Stackoverflow.

Comment: A quick comment before you possibly re-post to Stack Overflow.  `QTimer.singleShot()` is an asynchronous function, so your current code is launching five, one-second timers at the same time, and not a one-second timer five times in a row or in series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, `QTimer.singleShot()` is not really what you want. I would suggest setting an interval, then connecting your slot function to the `timeout` signal of `QTimer` and calling `timer.start()`. Then, inside the function, check the value of `counter` and stop the timer when it reaches 5. Additionally, you have a typo (you wrote `counter=+1` instead of `counter+=1`) and also, to increment your counter variable properly from inside the function, you need to [global](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) it. If you were doing this inside a class, you would declare your counter variable as an instance attribute e.g. `self.counter`.

Try the following:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer# Required if running outside QGIS Python console

counter = 1

def shiftPoints():
    global counter
    print(counter)
    if counter == 5:
        timer.stop()
        print('Timer stopped')
        return
    counter+=1


timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000)
timer.timeout.connect(shiftPoints)
timer.start()
```

A minimal example of this inside a class:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer# Required if running outside QGIS Python console

class TimerDemo(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 1
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.shiftPoints)
        
    def shiftPoints(self):
        print(self.counter)
        if self.counter == 5:
            self.timer.stop()
            print('Timer stopped')
            return
        self.counter+=1
        
x = TimerDemo()
x.timer.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Without classes or global variables:

```py
from itertools import count

timer_printer = lambda t: print(t)
counter = count(1)  # start at 1
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000)  # 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: time_printer(next(counter)))
timer.start()
```